# Debezium CDC Connector task having error : javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I had my debezium mysql source connector working on Kafka. I added another debezium mysql source connector using the same database but with different data formats. As a result, my first connector started showing the following error :

```
[2019-07-11 10:29:09,125] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=debezium-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Encountered change event for table db.user whose schema isn't known to this connector
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:208)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:508)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:1095)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:943)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:580)
at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:825)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Encountered change event for table db.user whose schema isn't known to this connector
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.informAboutUnknownTableIfRequired(BinlogReader.java:758)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleUpdateTableMetadata(BinlogReader.java:733)
at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:492)
... 5 more
[2019-07-11 10:29:09,125] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=debezium- 
connector-krazybee-0} Task is being killed and will not recover 
until manually restarted 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
[2019-07-11 10:29:09,125] INFO Stopping MySQL connector task 
(io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnectorTask:430)
[2019-07-11 10:29:09,125] INFO ChainedReader: Stopping the binlog 
reader (io.debezium.connector.mysql.ChainedReader:121)
[2019-07-11 10:29:09,126] INFO Discarding 0 unsent record(s) due 
to the connector shutting down 
(io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader:129)
[2019-07-11 10:29:09,126] INFO Discarding 0 unsent record(s) due to the connector shutting down (io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader:129)
```

I have restarted the debezium connector using REST API.

Though I understood to the best of my knowledge that the debezium connector is having a mismatch in database history schema, but unable to figure out how to correct it without deleting the existing connector.

I also reloaded the existing connector with previous values using PUT request but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the same `database.history.kafka.topic` for both connectors. You should use unqiue topic for each instance.

Comment: I have two connectors with the different values for `database.history.kafka.topic` and still get `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException`  when trying to add the second connector. What is the solution? I'm fine with disabling MBean/JMX altogether. Please advise.